# Meaning URL in $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am reading a bout `$http` service in a book.
There is a sample that I do understand the whole sample except the `url` part.

I do not understand where is the url? or how can I find it?

```
module.factory('memberDataStoreService', function ($http) {
                var memberDataStore = {};
                memberDataStore.doRegistration = function (theData) {
                    var promise = $http({method: 'POST', url: 'memberservices/register', data: theData});
                    return promise;
                }
                return memberDataStore;
```

even in my `error` promise , I try to see what kind of status my error has , I just get zero

```
 promise.error(function (data, status) {
                            $scope.showErrorMessage = true;
                            $scope.wrong  = status;
                        });
```

this is my code for printing the error message

```
<div class="error" ng-show="showErrorMessage">
     There appears to have been a problem with your registration.<br/>
      {{wrong}}
      <br/>
</div>
```

I get this error when I try to debug it

> ```
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
> http://localhost:8383/CustomService/memberservices/register Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
> ```

Comment: is there a typo in "ng-modle"

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The URL is where you configured it... `url: 'memberservices/register'`

Comment: @Phil     this is not my code. this is a sample code from a book. the book did not explain this part very well. I try to understand where it is cuz I keep getting error. How did the sample configure this? can you explain how I can rectify my error and be able to get success message?

Comment: In order to POST, you would need a server-side handler. I suggest you leave the book (which is probably out of date) and read through the [PhoneCat Tutorial App](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) or the [angular-seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed)

Comment: @Phil the book is for 2014? I know angular-seed a little but how it is gonna help my situation?

Comment: angular-seed is a **modern** example of how to write an AngularJS application

Comment: @phil could please be kind and tell me how is gonna help me here ? I have wampserver installed in my laptop

Comment: Ok, if you want to write an app that communicates with a server-side API, you're going to need something to handle the server-side requests. For example, with WAMP, you would have a PHP script handle the POST request at `memberservices/register`.

Comment: No, this is simply too broad. If it's [the book I think it is](http://www.apress.com/9781484201619), Chapter 7 deals with *Server Communication*. I can't find anything beyond the title but I assume that's where it talks about server-side processes and APIs

Comment: @Phil but I do not understand why the book did not explain it well?

Comment: The examples in that book appear to be academic in nature and not actually practical / runnable. I would find a better guide if you're interested in creating both back and front-ends

Comment: @Phil please if it is not a trouble. :)

Answer (score -1):

Hey man do you have a server a node server or any other one to handle requests at this url
http://localhost:8383/CustomService/memberservices/register if you than you can only expect no error

Comment: can you explain your answer better? I do not have a node server but I have a local host? is local host as same as a server? I have wampserver installed

Comment: ok no problem now if you know php write a server in it to handle a request on the url http://localhost:8383/CustomService/memberservices/register

Comment: let me search for you

Comment: I don't understand php very well so I think this can help you http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/